# Highlight A Row On Condition

Tags: angular, typescript, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am trying to highlight a row upon condition in a table. Am using **Jqxgrid** and did something in the front-end to highlight:

**TypeScript**:

```
carsDataAgain = [
    {
      year: '1967',
      make: 'Pontiac',
      model: 'GTO',
      id: '1002',
    },
];

getCarsData(val: string) {
    //console.log(model);
    if (this.carsDataAgain.find((i) => i.model === val.model)) {
      return 'Matched';
    } else {
      return 'Unmatched';
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<jqxGrid
  [theme]="'material'"
  [width]="getWidth()"
  [source]="hello"
  [columns]="columns"
  [pageable]="true"
  [autoheight]="true"
  [sortable]="true"
  [selectionmode]="'singlerow'"
  [altrows]="true"
  [enabletooltips]="true"
  [editable]="true"
  [filterable]="'true'"
  [columngroups]="columngroups"
  [keyboardnavigation]="'false'"
  enablekeyboarddelete="false"
  [ngClass]="{
    primary: getCarsData(hello) === 'Matched',
    secondary: getCarsData(hello) === 'Unmatched'
  }"
>
</jqxGrid>
```

In the front-end, I did something as follows using `ngClass`:

```
[ngClass]="{
    'primary': getCarsData(hello) === 'Matched',
    'secondary': getCarsData(hello) === 'Unmatched'
}"
```

So what am doing, passed the data source in the method and checked the returned value to highlight. In my end, am verifying if there's an existing model (GTO) in the **carsDataAgain** array, then highlight. As there's a matching model, then it should highlight the first row. Here's a sample that I tried so far: [Highlight A Row](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jqxgrid-editable-frh821?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Is there any other way to implement it or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main issues with your solution:

1. You were adding the class to the table itself not a specific row
2. Even if that was correct getCarsData was being called ad infinitum because of angular render cycle, you can see that in the console.

I modified your stackblitz to make it work here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jqxgrid-editable-njsbfh

basically you create an arrow function and send it to a property called cellclassname when defining the grid columns

```
  cellclass = (row, column, value, rowData) => {

    if (this.carsDataAgain.find((i) => i.model === rowData.model)) {
      return 'green';
    }
  };
  ...
  columns: any[] = [
  {
      text: 'Year',
      datafield: 'year',
      width: 40,
      cellclassname: this.cellclass,
    },
    { text: 'Id', datafield: 'id', width: 40, cellclassname: this.cellclass },
    {
      text: 'Model',
      datafield: 'model',
      width: 100,
      cellclassname: this.cellclass,
    },
    {
      text: 'Make',
      datafield: 'make',
      width: 100,
      cellclassname: this.cellclass,
    },
  ];
```

Also for jqxgrid to be able to see the css classes defined in the app component we need a

```
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

which means that the styles from app.component.css will be global. You could also define the classes in another global css file and it would work without the encapsulation change.